# How to search and replace and keep case in Notepad++?

Tags: search, replace, notepad++

Is it possible to **search and replace** a string using **Notepad++** and keep the case (small or big caps) formatting?

For example, I have the following strings that are often used in several files:

```
UserLogin
USERLOGIN
userlogin
```

Now, I need to name everything "consumer" instead of "user". Like this:

```
ConsumerLogin
CONSUMERLOGIN
consumerlogin
```

Is there anyway of doing this change with only 1 search/replace in Notepad++? Or I have to do 3 different search/replace?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this other than using macros (which doesn't help if your replace criteria changes)?

Comment: No, at the end I did it using the macro.. So question still open.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do 3 search/replace, but you can create a macro to "group" them. Start a macro, do the 3 replaces then stop the macro. (`Macro > Start/Stop Recording`). Click `Macro > Save Currently Recorded Macro` and choose a Name and Shortcut for later uses.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Well, not exactly what I had in mind. But the Macro function is a good alternative. Thanks for answering.